# alternatives to Gnu screen under Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gnu-screen, tmux, byobu

Are there any terminal multiplexers for Cygwin/Windows other than Gnu's screen?

I know of 2 alternatives to the Gnu's screen application: Byobu and TMux. However, neither of these run under Windows using Cygwin.

Comment: This question is now out of date. It is possible to run tmux under Cygwin. http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/tmuxInCygwin.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed neither byobu nor tmux are available as Cygwin packages, but you could try building them from source. Lots of programs do build without Cygwin-specific patches these days.

(Btw, byobu actually is Screen, but with a fancy default configuration.)

Comment: As a little update on the matter: tmux is now available on cygwin (as is tmux) as a package, available through the default cygwin installer.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the current byobu version (5.18) works out of the box on cygwin.

To install it, I did the following:

1. download byobu from https://launchpad.net/byobu
2. `tar xzpf byobu-* && cd byobu-*`
3. install make and screen in cygwin
4. `./configure && make && make install`

and byobu is working...

Comment: You need pyhton module `snack` for it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks much!  Worked for me in latest MSYS2.  Does anybody know how i can apply `screenrc`/`screen_layout` configs?  I have a 3 split pane that im already accustomed to. Maybe there's an easy way to split the panes that I havent seen yet.

Comment: @BrianThomas please open a new question.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, tmux isn't buildable for Cygwin - something to do with Unix Domain sockets not working right in that environment. Sad, I know.

Comment: Here's an explanation from the tmux-users list:
http://www.mail-archive.com/tmux-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01347.html

Answer (score 1):

I would like to update this with a note that I have successfully installed byobu under Cygwin 1.7.9 - although I may have implicitly installed other dependencies, I was able to download the source, compile, and install with absolutely zero issue. I received the same route file note but it did not stop it from loading- the python error will though

Comment: Would you be kind enough to write the steps you have undertaken? Maybe on a blog or something?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the cygwin gnu screen package.

Then I downloaded the latest byobu tarball and installed it following it's readme-file. But after installation I could not run it, I gave up at this point:

```
Administrator@ntmachine ~
$ byobu
/bin/byobu/lib/byobu/include/shutil: line 292: /proc/net/route: No such file or
directory
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

It would be easy to meet the python requirement in the last line, but I believe the /proc/net/route issue would be difficult.

So I will use screen now on cygwin instead of byobu.

There does not seem to be a tmux package. And as camperdave pointed out, it could be not buildable for cygwin.

Comment: Howdy!  If you file this as a bug against byobu at bugs.launchpad.net/byobu, I'll do my best to fix it.  (Upstream maintainer of byobu here).

Comment: How would you use screen on `cygwin`, im my case `msys2`?  I cant find a way to build the source, does anybody have a source and a way to build, e.g. a `configure` file or a `makepkg` present?